# How can I activate a second monitor displaying a second screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, twinview

I am new to Linux. I have Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.16.0-33-generic kernel. 
I would like to use a second monitor and have a second desktop projected there (I have read this is know as Twinview).

I installed ARandR and the NVIDIA X Server Settings menu (of which I got only a simplified version) but they do not display an option to activate a second desktop in the other monitor. I just have two screens (my laptop's and the monitor) showing the same. 
Can anybody please help me to fix this?

Comment: have you tried settings -> screens ?

Comment: I did, but there is not an option to configure the two monitors.

Comment: Check if you have mirror screens selected. If so, uncheck it.